# Is there any way to use radio buttons with different ids in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of radio buttons. is there any way to use each of them with different ids as I have to send some value to database when they are checked.
Due to multiple checking of radio buttons at a single time i have to use different Ids which I am unable in rails.
Please help

Comment: Are you looking for a different ID for each radio button? Or for different groups of radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"multiple checking of radio buttons" ? You don't want radio button then; you want checkboxes.

Comment: no I dnt want... as in check boxes they can store only either 1 or 0... but i need more than that so....